# HTML input type password gets into MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, html, passwords

I have recently started to pick up frontend stuffs and been writing a very simple web app for my workplace where each of the users are required to **log in**. They have already been given a preset account (pattern: Txx, xx stands for staff number) and a password, saved in a MySQL.

[login box on UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIuTa.png)

[input type is password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsLaW.png)

Log-in was technically workable. Originally as I had set input **type** = **"password"** so the password box showed ******** when they did the input on browser.

Nevertheless, when I checked phpMyAdmin page and get into the 'user' table of my DB, **where usernames and passwords are saved for PHP checking,** I can actually see the password (I logged in with root...)!

[blue paints hiding exact numerical passwords the users use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmcAL.png)

Isn't it supposed that even admin(root?) cannot see the password?

Is it that chrome browser might actually have understood the 'type is password' and encrypted the input and send to PHP which programs to save password on MySQL?  (I did not use any functions like md5(xxx) in my HTML codes however...)

Is anything wrong (or should be done) to mySQL setting? Or did Chrome actually NOT encrypt the inputs before sending to PHP?

Comment: You are correct; Chrome does **not** add any automatic encryption for you when POSTing to a server-side script. You'll have to write the PHP function to encrypt your data before it gets stored in your database, and the relevant function to decrypt your data when retrieving it from the database. It's a complex process that can easily go wrong, so I recommend [**this WikiHow article**](https://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL).

Comment: Thanks, here is what I do: I applied a md5 function in phpmyAdmin page over the records using SQL query, and all the passwords became 'md5-hashed', and then on a php that processes user password to check with MySQl record, I applied $md5_password = $_Session['password'] = md5(_POST['password'];     and $md5_password (passed on to MySQL query as a parameter(or variable?))...worked. So the concept is the password changed the way it READS and passed around -- a long human-unreadable string.

Answer (score -1):

Chrome does not encrypt the password for you. you have to do it yourself by hashing it when saving it to your database

Read more about it here
http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have used md5 to process the input password before sending it to compare with the db records of passwords which are also md5-changed!